# Cannot install network-manager-l2tp on Ubuntu18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, vpn

Trying to install network-manager-l2tp on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp-gnome
```

After this command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp
```

I am getting this:

```
    ...    
    E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
    E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/seriy-pr/network-manager-l2tp/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The ppa you added is not meant to be used on 18.04. Contact the developer on https://launchpad.net/~nm-l2tp/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp and ask them to release a Bionic version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xenial repository does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/xenial-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: @N0rbert only in the case of the question you linked to, there *was* an updated ppa. I'm not so sure one exists for this package.

Comment: @Jos, right. Retracted vote. But it seems that PPA is not needed. Packages are already in [universe pocket](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=network-manager-l2tp&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all) (including [`libreswan`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=+libreswan&searchon=names)).

Comment: @N0rbert Good find! Care to write an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we discovered during conversation with @Jos in comments:

the mentioned PPA ([`ppa:ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp`](https://launchpad.net/~nm-l2tp/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp)) is not needed for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

If you have added it - remove it with:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp
```

All packages are available in the *universe* repository (see [link for `network-manager-l2tp`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=network-manager-l2tp&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all) and [link for `libreswan`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=+libreswan&searchon=names)).

So all you need is to enable universe repository and install packages from it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp-gnome
```

Comment: Perhaps the obsolete ppas should be `ppa-purge`d as well?

Comment: Thanks, I could install network-manager-l2tp-gnome without ppa:nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp repository

Comment: Issue: sudo add-apt-repository universe
Get:'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
Issue: sudo apt-get update
Get: Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/ubuntu bionic Release                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Issue: sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp-gnome
Get: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
network-manager-l2tp-gnome is already the newest version (1.2.8-2build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1......

Comment: Have been trying for weeks to get l2tp VPN to work.... with MERAKI's. Still no luck. So far the only reason I have the need for a Windows VM in Virtualbox.